# How to do Darboux sums

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone explain to me how do I find out if it is upper or lower Darboux sum and on which interval is it? Here is example, it says that it is uppear Darboux sum on interval $[0,1]$.

[image]

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sum corresponds to the function $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ on the partition $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^n$ with $x_k=k/n$, $0\le k\le n$. The sum is $\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})$. Since $f$ is decreasing, $f(x_k)=\inf_{x_{k-1}\le x\le x_k}f(x)$. The sum is thus a lower sum.